# Explain why $\Pr (| Z -\alpha | \le | Y - \alpha |) \ge \frac{1}{2} $

Tags: probability

We have independent variables with the same distribution:
$$ X_1, X_2, ..., X_ {2n} $$
Let
$$Z = \frac {X_ {n + 1} + \dots + X_ {2n}} {n} $$
$$Y = \frac {X_1 + \dots + X_ {n}} {n} $$
And now in my book is written:
$$Pr (| Z -\alpha | \le | Y - \alpha |) \ge \frac{1}{2} $$
Why is this inequality is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $\{| Z -\alpha | \leqslant | Y - \alpha |\}\cup\{| Y -\alpha | \leqslant | Z - \alpha |\}$ is the entire sample space and $(Y,Z)$ and $(Z,Y)$ have the same distribution hence $2\Pr(| Z -\alpha | \leqslant | Y - \alpha |)\geqslant1$.

Comment: @ Did - I am also curious to know this answer but don't follow all of your notation. would you mind giving a worded version. If it is something that would be long and wonky then no worries.

Comment: @mathtastic Which part is unclear?

Comment: I should say that to a more indoctrinated person your answer is probably perfectly clear - my own ignorance of the notation is making this hard to interpret. Perhaps a better solution is for me to hunt down a good site to learn this notation!

Comment: @mathtastic Once again: which part(s) (of the notations) is (are) unclear?

Comment: I don't understand too. Could you try explain it simplier ?

Comment: @xaweyNEW Which part of "Which part of the answer is unclear?" is unclear?

Comment: $$Pr(|Z-\alpha| \le |Y - \alpha|) + Pr (|Z-\alpha| \ge |Y - \alpha|) = 2 Pr (|Z-\alpha| \ge |Y - \alpha|) = 2 Pr(|Z-\alpha| \le |Y - \alpha|) \ge 1 \Rightarrow Pr(|Z-\alpha| \le |Y - \alpha|) \ge \frac12
$$ Is it thanks to 'the same distribution' ?

Comment: Yes. Still other mysteries?

Comment: Interesting downvotes--purely for mathematical reasons, to be sure.